# Shows error in webdriver

Tags: android, python, automation, appium

I wrote a unit test case in python for automating login screen of my app. I am using Appium. I got error in the following line. I have set the desired capabilities.

```
desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '6.0.1'
desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'Redmi 3S'
desired_caps['app'] = '/Users/sanju/Desktop/myapp.apk'



class Utils(object) :
@staticmethod

def initialswipes(driver):
    for _ in range(0, 5):
        try :
            driver.execute_script("mobile: swipe", {"direction": "left"})
        except WebDriverException :
            return False
    return True


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
def test_something(self):
   driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
```

Error is:
  File "/Users/sanju/PycharmProjects/Android/Login.py", line 37, in test_something
    driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)

Comment: Have you started appium server?

Comment: Yes. I have started the appium server.

Comment: It would be great if you can post the entire error that you get.

Comment: got resolved. anyway thanks for the help